# How to make Lotus Notes 9 display post time in inbox?

Tags: lotus-notes, date-time

When I receive mail from an internet mail server, all incoming mail is displayed with the date/time of the replication. How can I change this? I would like to have the date/time visible in the inbox view when the mail has been sent by originator. I'm using Lotus Notes 9 Social Edition on Windows 8.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a domino designer, then you can change this. If not- then you need somebody to do this for you in a template and send it to you.

You just open the folder inbox in the designer and change the formula of the date- column from posteddate to delivereddate (or vice versa, i'm not 100% sure)..